# Google Scholar detects that I want to scrape it with curl in PHP

Tags: php, curl, web-scraping, google-scholar

I'm trying to scrape Google Scholar using curl in PHP. I have already defined a user-agent for curl and I have enabled CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE and CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR by creating a cookie directory. Yet, Google automatically detects that I'm scraping it. I think it's probably because curl cannot parse JavaScript codes, but I'm not sure.

Is it possible to scrape Google Scholar using curl in PHP? Do I need to use a headless browser? If yes, how can I config a headless browser to work with curl in PHP? Can I use a different programming language alongside PHP and somehow make them work together to give a graphic output to the user?

Thanks in advance

Comment: haveyou tried the alternative which is the API instead?

Comment: @Ghost Unfortunately, to the best of my knowledge, Google offers no API for Google Scholar. :| I googled it and found a thousands of complaints about this from researchers.

Comment: how bout this one? https://github.com/ckreibich/scholar.py invoke the script using PHP and just parse the return values, or if you are well versed with python, you could probably port it to PHP

Comment: @Ghost I have tested that one. The main problem with it is that it works only half of the time. :( But the second part of your comment is actually an alternative solution that I'm looking for more information about it. How can I invoke a script in a different language using PHP and parse the returned values? And please tell me about what you mean by "porting" it to PHP.

Comment: there's an `exec()` function in PHP that lets you invoke a bash script, its not just limited to that, you can do something else too. here's the entry http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php

Comment: and port means transcribing the script written from python to PHP, as a last resort

Comment: @Ghost Yes, but I have disabled all functions like exec, system, passthru in my php.ini for obvious security reasons. Can I force python to run something like a webserver on my server that can be connected only via localhost?

Comment: that i'm not sure, (and regarding your circumstance not sure what to advice you more) i'm not a python expert but i'm pretty sure you can invoke a python script thru an http request, for that you'll need to research too

Comment: @Ghost Thank you for your helpful comments. I appreciate it a lot. :)